# How can i automatically upload dSYM files to my server without using any third party library in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, dsym, symbolicate

I am working on my crash reporting SDK and I need dSYM files to symbolicate my crashes. How can I automatically upload them to my own server for symbolication purposes? I've looked around quite a lot, but every question seems to be addressing uploading dSYM to Firebase Crashlytics. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Especially since larger analytics SDKs such as Crashlytics require the user to “upload symbols” to symbolicate reports.

Comment: @loremipsu, in case of Firebase Crashlytics, it require user to add a Run Script in build Phases in order to automatically upload dSYM to its server.

Comment: But I am confused about this line

"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"

How this command is able to upload dSYM behind the scenes?

Comment: Open the file and look at it. I don’t know off the top of my head but that would be the place where I would start looking.